# How to set -v compiler option in CLion and see respective results

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clion

I get the following error when linking my c++ code in CLion:

"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" due failure to find a link-object for architecture x86_64.

How can I set the -v opion (linking or compiling option???) and how can I see respective results (invocation)?

In general, where can I see in CLion what the compiler is actually doing, e.g. which flags it uses, which files are compiled, linked, etc.

Comment: CLion uses CMake by default, so all the building options should be in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to pass

```
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
```

inside CMake configuration

[image]

`CLion | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake`